# Json.NET - preserve type information when type is unknown

Tags: json, serialization, ravendb, json.net

I would like to send Json to the server, and we do that with Newtonsoft's [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx)<sup>1</sup>. The json may contain type information (*"$type" = ...*). This type info may point to an unknown type. Said object would typically be contained in a property of type object.

---

### What I would like to do:

- Convert the part of the unknown type to a JObject
- Preserve somehow the type information, so I can send the **same** json back to the client at a later point as it was passed to the server.

---

### What I've tried so far

- By replacing the `SerializationBinder` on the `JsonSerializer`, I can force Json.NET to deserialize the json contained into a `JObject`. This is *almost* what I would like to have, alas the *$type* property is lost.
- In the binder returning a type that points to an object that would work in harmony with a custom `JsonConverter` which would gobble up the offending object such that upon write it would faithfully recreate the json as it was encountered. However, when you hit the $type info, no converters will be called anymore, apparently we are then in a different branch of the json.NET code
- One can handle a serialization error, try to read from the reader the *offending* part, then one could create a JOBject manually and annotate the type information.

<sup>1) More specific - the built of it that is contained in the RavenDB.Abstractions, but hopefully they have not diverged too much.</sup>

Comment: This is an interesting problem.  Can you show your code for the `SerializationBinder` and the `JsonConverter` that you tried, along with the custom object it uses?  Also what do you mean by "when you hit the $type info, no converters will be called anymore"?

Comment: Did you disable TypeHandling? Couldn't you roll it yourself using a new Type property with `[JsonProperty("$type")]` and handle getting/setting yourself through the binder and converter?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69261839/json-net-handle-unknown-derived-types-when-using-typenamehandling